# using form-login in a Multi-tenant webapp using Spring MVC and Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, multi-tenant

I created a small and simple webapp using `Spring Security` and `SpringMVC` and I'm trying to convert it to be a multi-tenant application.
The concept I want is to re-use actual JSPs I have and alter their contents based on configuration which I determine based on the path of the URL.

Example:
Customer #1 (abc) - URL: http://mydomain.com/abc/login.html
Customer #2 (xyz) - URL: http://mydomain.com/xyz/login.html

So the name of the "tenant" is a prefix to the page's path.

I modified my controller to be like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/{customer:[a-zA-Z0-9]+}/login.htm")
public class LoginController 
{
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class);

    @RequestMapping
    @ReadOnlyRequest
    public String login(@PathVariable("customer") String customer, HttpServletRequest request) 
    {
        // Do some 'customer' related actions here

        return "login"; // Map to the 'login.jsp' view
    }
}
```

My view resolver configuration is:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
   <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
   <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
   <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Until now, I had the following `form-login` configuration:

```
<form-login 
   login-page="/login.htm"
   authentication-failure-url="/login.htm?error=true"
   login-processing-url="/login_process"
   default-target-url="/index.jsp"
   always-use-default-target="true"
/>
```

But I do not know how to convert it to support my changes.

Is there a way to convert it to something like:

```
<form-login 
  login-page="/${customer}/login.htm"
  authentication-failure-url="/${customer}/login.htm?error=true"
  login-processing-url="/${customer}/login_process"
  default-target-url="/index.jsp"
  always-use-default-target="true"
/>
```

Comment: I have opend a smiler discussion here..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627972/multi-tenant-webapp-using-spring-mvc-and-hibernate-4-2-0-final   ... But i can't find an answer for it.. Can you please post the source code about this?....I have been trying 3 days for this.

Comment: @edaklij -  the project I was working on was canceled before I implemented the advice I got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible idea is to use URL rewriting instead of manual handling of tenant identifiers. This way you can completely decouple tenant handling logic from your code, for example, as follows:

- You define an inbound rewriting rule that converts `/abc/login.html` to `/login.html` and saves tenant identifier as a request attribute.
- You define an outbound rule that appends the current tenant identifier to URLs being written into response. I think Spring Security should respect such a rule when sending redirects (if it doesn't, you can define a custom `RedirectStrategy`).

Though I have not tested this idea and cannot be sure that it would work.

**See also:**

- [OCPSoft Rewrite](http://ocpsoft.org/rewrite/)
- [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)

Comment: The `form-login` configuration allows Spring to redirect a user to the login page when their session expires or when they input an incorrect url. 
I want a user going to any illegal url under `http://mydomain/abc/`, to be automatically redirected to `http://mydomain/abc/login.htm`. Currently I can redirect only to `http://mydomain/login.htm`.

Comment: Thank you - the URL re-writing filter seems like the best course of action - I might write one of my own but the general idea is exactly what I needed.